# Problems with Button click action in ListView

Tags: c#, android

I have a Listview with 2 buttons on it (+/-). When you click on one of them, the counter next to the buttons adds or substract by one. But when I click on a button, the counter changes on multiple ListView items.

I've tried several approaches to make sure that my events only get wired once, but nothing seems to work so far. Is there an alternative approach to wiring the click event to the listview buttons outside the GetView method of the adapter? Or am i missing something in my adapter to make sure it only changes the counter in the same View?

[image: app example]

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
      var item = _items [position];
      View view = convertView;

      if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
             view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.list_detailview, null);

      view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.tvMenuName).Text = item.MenuName;    
      TextView txtQuantity = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.txtQuantityDrinks);

      if (item.First != true) 
      {
            var btnPlus = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnPlus);    
        var btnMin = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnMin);
            btnMin.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
            {
                 item.Ordered--;
                 txtQuantity.Text = item.Ordered.ToString ();
                 OrderManager.I.OrderList.Remove (item);
            }; 

            btnPlus.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => 
            {
                 item.Ordered++;
                 txtQuantity.Text = item.Ordered.ToString();
                 OrderManager.I.OrderList.Add(item);
            };

            item.First = true;
       }

       view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imgDetailView).SetImageResource (ResourceManager.I.getResId(item.Icon));

        return view;
 }
```

Comment: Is there a pattern or do they all increment and decrement together? I'm not certain, but it looks to me that you're binding your increment/decrement events for each item of your list to the same button, so it would make sense that they all would change.

Comment: I can't see any pattern for now. If i find anything i'll post it. I don't think i bind every event to the same button because they all work. Every time i click on one it increments/decrements on the right spot, but it does it on other "random" items too.